# Cannot resolve class androidx.preference.internal.PreferenceImageView

Tags: android, androidx

[image]

```
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'
```

[image]

I don't know why I'm getting `Cannot resolve class error` when I've already added `androidx.preference` dependency in my Gradle file. The project syncs well, but I can't get rid of the error. Perhaps was it removed? Renamed?

Comment: Sometimes it can be IDE bug/hang and you can normally run the app; is this your case?

Comment: I didn't try yet, I'm trying to get rid of some errors in project before I do so...

Answer (score 0):

I think the **legacy implementation** is unnecessary it should not be required and I think it is making the issue. Just remove it, [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference#groovy) doesn't say you need it. Also its version is 1.0.0 (older than your main implementation)

Comment: I resorted to legacy implementation because the recent one wasn't working. I removed legacy implementation now, but like I said earlier nothing changes. The error still exists

Comment: Is your project in Java or Kotlin?